# Update Text Field While Automating iPhone App

Tags: iphone, xpath, textbox

I am automating an iPhone App. The scenario is Login Logout and re-Login. But while re-login the username and password field is displaying the  details. I am trying to list that xpath as a WebElement and clear() that field if(Webelement.gettext() !="") But it is not happening as in the existing framework is taking xpath as String and typecast the String to WebElement is not Possible. Is there any other way to achieve that?? Kindly Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this method before passing the value to the Locator.

```
method_name(){
Actions actionObj = new Actions(driver);
actionObj.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
         .sendKeys(Keys.chord("A"))
         .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).keyUp(keys.DELETE)
         .perform();
}
```

findElement By xpath add a condition like getText()!="" and then  It will be done. 
Is it working??